# why does there exist a unitary matrix U for every symmetric matrix A such that $A=UDU^{\dagger}$ where D is a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, number-theory

I am not able to see why this is true but it looks a bit like the Jacobian rule? Any explanation on why this is true would be much appreciate!

Comment: Where do the coefficients of A and the diagonal matrix come from reals or complex numbers?

Comment: Your title, as you wrote it , is absolutely false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the spectral theorem. See the normal matrix section of the wiki page

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem